# How to get index of dynamically classed element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used countless Stack Overflow solutions through the years but this is my first time posting.

I am building an in-page search tool on a Wordpress site that functions similarly to a browser's Find feature. When the user starts typing in the search field, matched letters are surrounded by a span with class="highlight" which has a green background. This works fine.

I also want the ability to iterate through the matches. When the Next or Previous button is clicked, the "current" is added to the span class -  class="highlight current" which has a yellow background. With each click of the Next button, the next match is highlighted in yellow. The Previous button highlights the previous match.

I am using jQuery's .index() and .eq() methods to determine which matched span to add the "current" class to. The problem I'm having is $('.highlight').index('current') only matches elements as they are after the first click and not after subsequent clicks.

Here is the pertinent part of my code:

```
$('.search-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_matches = [];
    $('.highlight').each(function() {
        total_matches.push(this);
    });
    console.log(total_matches.length);//total number of matched terms on the page

    var current_selected = $('.highlight').index('current');
    //term currently highlighted in yellow, -1 if nothing is highlighted.
    //It ALWAYS returns -1, which is the problem    

    if( $(this).hasClass( 'search-next') ) {//click Next button
        if(current_selected === -1) {//nothing currently selected
            $( $('.highlight').eq(0) ).addClass('current');//highlight first element
        }else{//something already selected
            current_selected = (current_selected+1) % all_matches.length;
            $( $('.highlight').eq(current_selected) ).addClass('current');
        }
    }
    //something similar for the search-prev button....
});
```

I'm missing something having to do with the "current" class being dynamically added and removed but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `.index('.current')`

Answer (score 2):

If `current` is a class then you will need to prepend a period.

Without the period, it is looking for the index of a `<current></current>` selector instead of `<anything class="current"></anything>`

So try replacing this:
`var current_selected = $('.highlight').index('current');`

with this:
`var current_selected = $('.highlight').index('.current');`

---

I also noticed you were double wrapping jQuery on certain functions `$( $('element') )` is not necessary.

---

Lastly, if you don't ever use `total_matches` you could get the length of `$('.highlight')` without looping through it.

```
$('.search-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_matches = $('.highlight').length; // shorter than looping through

    console.log(total_matches);//total number of matched terms on the page

    var current_selected = $('.highlight').index('.current'); // fix is here

    if(! $(this).hasClass( 'search-next') ) return; // I find this easier than indenting everything below

    if (current_selected === -1) {//nothing currently selected
        $('.highlight').eq(0).addClass('current');//highlight first element             
    } else {//something already selected
        current_selected = (current_selected+1) % total_matchces;
        $('.highlight').eq(current_selected).addClass('current');
    }
    //something similar for the search-prev button....
});
```

Comment: Using your suggestions, I am closer to a solution but am having another issue. I will post a separate question

Answer (score 1):

You never remove the `current` class from previously selected elements, so only the first will always be selected.