# jQuery index() returns unexpected result

Tags: jquery

Building off of a [previous question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444507/how-to-get-index-of-dynamically-classed-element-with-jquery)...

I am coding an in-page search tool that functions similarly to a browser's Find feature. When the user starts typing in the search field, matched letters are surrounded by a span with `class="highlight"` which has a green background. This works fine.

I also want the ability to iterate through the matches. When the Next or Previous button is clicked, the "current" class is added to the span class - `class="highlight current"` which has a yellow background. With each click of the Next button, the next match is highlighted in yellow. The Previous button highlights the previous match.

The code:

```
$('.search-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_matches = $('.highlight').length;

    var current_selected = $('.highlight').index('.current');
    //index of term currently highlighted in yellow, -1 if nothing is highlighted.

    if( $(this).hasClass( 'search-next') ) {//Next button has been clicked
        var select_me_next = (current_selected+1) % total_matches;
        $('.highlight').eq(select_me_next).addClass('current');
        $('.highlight').eq(current_selected).removeClass('current');
    }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'search-prev') ) {
    //something similar for the search-prev button....
    }
});
```

On the first click, `current_selected` = -1, which is correct
On the second click, `current_selected` = 0, which is correct
On the third click, `current_selected` = -1 again, should be 1. Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.index` incorrectly. When the argument is a selector, it indicates the collection to search for the object you applied it to, so `$('.highlight').index('.current')` means to find the position of `.highlight` within the `.current` collection. This is the opposite of what you want.

You should use `$('.current').index('.highlight')` or `$('.highlight').index($('.current'))` (when the argument is an object rather than a selector, it's the element to find the position of).

And to remove the old selected element, use `$('.highlight.current')` rather than using `.eq(current_selected)`. The reason for this is when `current_selected` is negative, `.eq()` counts from the end, which removes the class from the wrong element.

```js
$('.search-btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var total_matches = $('.highlight').length;

  var current_selected = $('.current').index('.highlight');
  //index of term currently highlighted in yellow, -1 if nothing is highlighted.

  if ($(this).hasClass('search-next')) { //Next button has been clicked
    var select_me_next = (current_selected + 1) % total_matches;
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('search-prev')) {
    select_me_next = current_selected - 1;
    if (select_me_next < 0) {
      select_me_next = total_matches - 1;
    }
  }

  $('.highlight.current').removeClass('current');
  $('.highlight').eq(select_me_next).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: green;
}
.highlight.current {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="highlight">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<button class="search-btn search-next">
  Next
</button>
<button class="search-btn search-prev">
  Prev
</button>
<div id="which"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between using a selector and an object with .index() so well. I've read that jquery doc page a dozen times and didn't get it.

Comment: It's definitely counterintuitive that it behaves so differently in the two forms. Note that if the elements are like my example, you can just use `$(".current").index()`, since it defaults to the index within the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `.index()` with a selector passed in the method.  Instead I've done something like this.

```
var index = -1;
$('.highlight').each(function(i){
   if($(this).hasClass('current')){
      index = i;
   };
});
```

Does this return the correct result?